# Django REST framework, dealing with related fields on creating records

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Preliminary note: this is a rather newbie question, though I have not found a sufficient answer on StackOverflow; many similar questions, but not this one. So I am asking a new question.

The problem: I'm having difficulty creating records where one field is a foreign key to an existing record, and I do not know what I'm doing wrong in my code.

In my app there are two models in question, a one-to-many relationship between Company and BalanceSheet:

models:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    cik = models.IntegerField(default=0, unique=True)
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=4, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.symbol

class BalanceSheet(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='balance_sheets',)
    date = models.DateField()
    profit = models.BigIntegerField()
    loss = models.BigIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('company', 'date'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.company, self.date)
```

serializers:

```
class BalanceSheetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    company = serializers.StringRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = BalanceSheet
        fields = ('company','date','profit','loss')


class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('cik', 'symbol', 'name')
```

Views:

```
class BalanceSheetCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    model = BalanceSheet
    queryset = BalanceSheet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BalanceSheetSerializer
```

urls include:

```
url(r'^(?P<symbol>[A-Z]{1,4})/create-balance-sheet/$', views.BalanceSheetCreate.as_view(),
        name='create_balance_sheet'),
```

To this point, I have zero problem reading data. However, when trying to create records, I get errors I don't understand:

```
curl http://localhost:8000/financials/AAPL/create-balance-sheet/ -X POST -d "company=AAPL&date=1968-04-17&profit=1&loss=1"
IntegrityError at /financials/AAPL/create-balance-sheet/
null value in column "company_id" violates not-null constraint
```

Dropping the company data from that curl command results in the same error.

How do I get around this error? I thought I was telling the api what company I'm interested in, both explicitly in the url and in the post data.

Using python3.6, django 1.11, and djangorestframework 3.7.7

Comment: Do you really need `null=true` for the foreign key?

Comment: toggling that value doesn't change any outcomes, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the `IntegrityError` because your code will try to create a new `BalanceSheet` without a company. That's because `StringRelatedField` is read-only (see [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield)) and therefore it's not parsed when `BalanceSheetSerializer` is used in write mode.

[`SlugRelatedField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) is what you need here:

```
class BalanceSheetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    company = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='symbol')

    class Meta:
        model = BalanceSheet
        fields = ('company','date','profit','loss')
```

Comment: Thanks. This is really helpful, though I'm now running into queryset issues. Do you know a resource on writing to the API, other than the official docs? The official docs seemed to be geared towards reading, and appear outdated at time. (see the python 2 style print statement in "Inspecting relationships.")

Comment: I don't know, there are many resources & tutorials if you do a web search... If you have a specific issue or something you don't understand, please post it to SO so people can help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, here's what I wound up with. Thanks again go to dukebody.

models:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    cik = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.symbol


class BalanceSheet(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='balance_sheets',)
    date = models.DateField()
    profit = models.BigIntegerField()
    loss = models.BigIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('company', 'date'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.company, self.date)
```

serializers:

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('cik', 'symbol', 'name')


class BalanceSheetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    company = CompanySerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = BalanceSheet
        fields = ('company', 'date', 'profit', 'loss')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        company_data = validated_data['company']
        company, created = Company.objects.get_or_create(**company_data)
        validated_data['company'] = company
        sheet = BalanceSheet.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return sheet
```

I also had to include the full company data within my curl statement as a nested dict.